# python setup.py put data files in %APPDATA% directory

Tags: python, setup.py

I would like to copy a default config file to %APPDATA%\foo directory when installing the package.

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name = 'foo',
    version = '0.1.0.dev1',
    author = 'me',
    packages = ['foo'],
    data_files=[(r'%APPDATA%\foo', ['foo.config'])]
)
```

The directory structure is:

- package top level

  - setup.py
  - foo.config
  - foo

    - **init**.py
    - bar.py

When I run python setup.py, it puts foo.config in the egg.  It outputs:

copying foo.config -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\%APPDATA%\foo

I am using python 3.5.  Can setuptools copy files to other directories determined by system variables, and is so how?

Answer (score 0):

Obvious in hindsight.  For some reason I didn't know you could have regular python code in setup.py.  Just import os and replace data_files above with:

```
data_files=[(os.path.join(os.environ['APPDATA'], 'foo'), ['foo.config'])]
```